# Creating the most basic title page.

Tags: titles

I want to create the most basic title page where by it only contains my name and the name of the project.
I am using share latex.

This is what I have put.

```
\title{blah blah}
\Author{Blah blah}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
```

This does not work, what do I need to do?

Comment: `\author` would be one correction I would make (lower case `a`)

Comment: If that doesn't work, and assuming you've got a `\documentclass` and you've added `\end{document}` I'm afraid you'll have to give us more information, as this should compile without error, assuming you're not using some tasty `\documentclass` with its own eccentricities

Comment: @Au101 it worked by using lower case.

Comment: Also this question is a little unclear. What is your problem? If your problem is that you're getting an error, that's probably due to your mistyped command name. If, however, you want a separate page, and this is just giving you a title at the top of the first page, that choice depends on the `documentclass`. A separate page is the default behaviour in `report` and `book`, for example, I believe, but not in `article`. You can use the `titlepage` option (`\documentclass[titlepage]{article}`) to force this behaviour in `article`. `notitlepage` forces the opposite behaviour with the other classes

Comment: If you are trying to lose the date, you can either redefine \maketitle or simply not use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said you are using share latex. When you create a new project in share latex, it automatically gives you some basic code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{blah blah}
\author{Blah blah }
\date{August 2016}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Then, all you have to do is delete \section{introduction} (and, if you want, delete the date line) and you get

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{blah blah}
\author{Blah blah }

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Which gives

[image]

So, there are a couple things to point out here:

1. In your code, you wrote \Author, instead of \author...that was the main problem.
2. If you want a specific title page, you're going to have to either use a different `\documentclass` or do as Au101 said, and put `\documentclass[titlepage]{article}`, which, assuming the previous code, gives

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great stuff. How can you do acknoweldgements?

Comment: @Aljabra, I'm not sure what you mean. You can do a section: `\section{Acknowledgements}` and type whatever there (if that's what you mean).

Comment: Oh yeah of course. Thanks. How do I not make it appear in the contents page?