# Omitting acknowledgements from the contents page

Tags: table-of-contents

How can I omit acknowledgements from the contents page?

This is what I have so far.

```
\section{Acknowledgements}
```

What do I need to add?

Comment: `\section*{Acknowledgements}` perhaps? Such a section should not be numbered anyway, so `\section*` is the better variant here!

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319369/remove-acknowledgments-from-the-table-of-contents?rq=1 .

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate Christian Hupfer's answer (and also referencing your previous question, [Creating the most basic title page.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324266/creating-the-most-basic-title-page/324268)), you can use the code

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum} %Just generates filler text

\title{blah blah}
\author{Blah blah}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2]%Yay filler text

\section*{Acknowledgements}
\lipsum[2]%More filler text

\end{document}
```

Which gives a title page, like this:

[image]

And a page with the table of contents, an introduction, and acknowledgements, like this:

[image]

Hope this helps!